# Rails_Admin trying to access a partial but it's returning 'undefined method' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I'm making a simple recipe app that accesses 3 tables:

> Ingredients,
>   Recipes,
>   Amounts (which contains a has_many_through join table and an 'amount' parameter)

I've installed rails_admin and am attempting to configure the view for the 'Amount' model.

Here's the config for the Amount model from my rails_admin.rb initializer.

```
config.model 'Amount' do

    list do
      exclude_fields :created_at, :updated_at
    end

    show do

      field :ingredient
      field :size
      field :recipe
      field :current_ingredients do
        partial :testpartial
      end

      exclude_fields :created_at, :updated_at
    end



    edit do

      field :recipe
      field :current_ingredients do
        partial :testpartial
      end

      field :ingredient
      field :size
      exclude_fields :amounts

    end
  end
```

And here's my _testpartial.html.erb partial file:

```
<strong>
<%=form.object.recipe.name.to_s %>
</strong>
</br>


<% ams=Amount.where(recipe_id: form.object.recipe_id) %>


<% ams.each do |a| %>
  <%= a.ingredient.name.to_s %>
  <%= a.size %>
  </br>
<% end %>
```

So here's my problem: when I run admin and go to a Amount:Edit page- the partial works perfectly - BUT when I go to a Amount:Show page I get this error:

undefined method `current_ingredients' for #

Please forgive me if I'm making to tool noob mistake - which I suspect I am - but I can't work out why it would make a difference if I was accessing the partial from the Show or Edit page?

Any help greatly appreciated.